# Retrieving certain column names from mysql table with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have been looking around, trying to find a way to retrieve column names (data type is boolean) only if it's "true"/"1".

For example I have this table with A,B,C,D,E,F as different column names and the boolean value below it,

```
A | B | C | D | E | F

1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0
```

What I wished to retrieve, which is only column names with a "true" value. So, my desired results from the query should only be  A,B and E.

Is there any way to do this? Or is it entirely impossible to accomplish and I should look to re-design my database?

With thanks in advance,
Xyles

Comment: Does your table only have one row of data? If it doesn't, how do you know which row to use for your boolean value?

Comment: I guess that @Xyles only showed the useful (for his question) data. My point is: when you do a `SELECT`, you already ask for some (or all) columns, in some order. This means that you should be able, given the results, to know which are the `true` columns.

Comment: Agree with @Cynical. You ask for all (*) or a set of columns that is given in your query, so extraction of a subset of the columns has to be left to the application layer.

Comment: @Xyles: It's not impossible to do this, BUT it's not the normative pattern for SQL programming; and generating the SQL to accomplish something like this is going to be unwieldy. There are other approaches that are much easier, such as using the the MySQL `SET` datatype. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A query cannot have different number of columns.  You could concatenate the names of the columns together with this:

```
select concat_ws(',', (case when A then 'A' else '' end),
                 (case when B then 'B' else '' end),
                 ...
                )
from t
```

You could also put them on separate rows, with a `union`:

```
select t.*, 'A'
from t
where A
union all
select t.*, 'B'
from t
where B
. . .
```

This puts the values on separate rows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But that does seems too much of a hassle. I guess I will re-design my database!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you reconsider your database design.

Returning column names can be done, but it's not the normative pattern for SQL programming, and the queries are going to be a lot more involved than they need to be.

If what you need to return is a string containing a comma separated list of values, with each value in the list representing a TRUE condition, I recommend you consider the MySQL `SET` datatype. e.g.

```
mycol SET('A','B','C','D','E','F') NOT NULL
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set.html

```
INSERT INTO mytable (mycol) VALUES ('A,B,E');

UPDATE mytable SET mycol = 'A,B,E' WHERE ...

SELECT mycol FROM mytable WHERE ...
```